# Can a child theme over-ride the parent theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a child theme which also has custom post types. I have the correct code in place to support thumbnails on these custom post types. I also have theme support added for `post-thumbnails`.

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'upcoming_events', 'directory_listings'));
```

However, this doesn't allow featured images to show in the custom post types. BUT when I add this to the parent theme (which has only post in the array for `add_theme_support`) the custom post types do show the featured image.

Is there a way to make the featured images show in the custom post type, without having to modify the parent theme (changes to that will, of course, be lost when updated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the priority argument in add_action to have the function load a little later..

```
function child_support() {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post', 'page', 'upcoming_events', 'directory_listings'));
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_support', 100 );
```

this should run after the parent themes hook (normal priority is 10, but the developer could have a later priority, so check if that value is above 100 if not working)

Comment: that did the trick! thanks for the help; didn't think about trying to laod mine after theirs